# SQLite - Returning records in a specific month and year in date

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get the records with a specific month and year like this:

```
SELECT * from table where strftime('%m', date) = '?'
```

if I test this query:

```
SELECT strftime('%m', date) from table
```

it return 19, but there's only records with may in month, so I thought the result was 5, but it's 19! Why?
What's wrong with my query? How can I return specific records using a specific value for month and year, linke 5 (may) and 2015

Comment: What is the format of the date values in the table?

Comment: I'm using inAndroid, I just insert a Date object, in database I see the milisseconds only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milliseconds is not one of SQLite's [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).
You have to convert these values into some supported format first (here: Unix timestamp):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE strftime('%m', date / 1000, 'unixepoch') = ?
```